# 80’s / 90’s animated movie that an alien can transform into other characters (animals)?

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a kid I used to watch an animated movie that revolves around this scenario: an alien is stuck in a planet. The characters are animals and the alien can transform into the characters and make a fuss.

I remember one scene that it transformed into the main character and they fight each other and they are sided and you could see that the copy had its eyes red so you could see the difference but the characters couldn’t see it.

Another scene is the one that the alien comes from a hill and there is some sound effects like it’s breathing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? Did you watch it on TV, and if so, in which country and language? And can you describe the default appearance of the alien?

Comment: Also, was the planet Earth, and did the animals look like ones from Earth, or were they alien animals?